# sudo command and root password on macOS

Tags: sudo, root

I'l try to make `sudo dd if=disk.img of=/dev/disk2`.

Root user is enabled with password. I logged in macOS as a single user.

When I try to set this command, terminal ask me `Password`, but root password did not work. Terminal write `Sorry, try again`.

What's wrong I do?

Answer (score 1):

For 'sudo dd' you use the password for the user that is logged in at that moment. 
You can also use 'sudo su' then use the same user password.
You can also become root with the 'su' command, in that case you use the root password.

Comment: In order to su to the root account, a user must belong to the group `wheel`.